# Bootstrap 4: gutter between columns in a row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, column-width, gutter

This layout is *almost* there, but I can't get gutters to appear between column divs in a row (right side, green). Also configuration of the width of the div holding all the rows (blue) is troublesome. The code is in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satchinden/a3j9Lv4s/135/), the layout pictured below. The main right-hand column will get some unknown number of items added dynamically. The left side and its items are static.

The core of it is pretty generic; maybe it's the overflow-y scrolling that's at issue? But I've tried many tweaks and nothing works:

```
<div class="wrapper-right" style="max-height:80%; overflow-y: scroll">
 <div class="row mx-1 mb-1">
  <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
    <p class="mt-0">item #1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
    <p class="mt-0">item #2</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 etc.
</div>
```

[image: bootstrap 4 layout w/nested rows in scrollable column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re looking to have a white space between your two columns, you can use your columns as containers for the content and create new content containers within the columns. That will give you a visible space between the two columns.

You can then set the two main columns to have a height of 100% to fill the space, and set your `content_right` container to flex and a direction of column. Remove all of the styles from the right wrapper (except the border) and add `overflow: auto`.

```css
#banner {
    background-color: goldenrod;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 77%;
    position: relative;
}

#content .row {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#content_left {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#content_right {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    /* overflow-y: scroll; */
}

.item-left {
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    ;
}

.item-right {
    min-height: 85px;
    background-color: beige;
    border-right: solid 0.375rem white;
    /* border: 2px dotted #ddd; */
}

.item-right + .item-right {
    border-left: solid 0.375rem white;
    border-right: none;
}

.wrapper-right {
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-1" style="height: calc(100vh - 12px); border: 1px solid #00ff00;">
    <div id="banner" class="w-100 my-1 p-2">
        <p>banner</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="row mx-0">
        <div class="col-sm-6 h-100">
            <div id="content_left" class="p-2">
                <div class="h5 w-100" style="background:#fff; text-align:center;">Left</div>
                <div class="content-wrapper p-1">
                    <div class="item-left mb-1 px-2">
                        <p class="mt-0">(l) item #1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-left mb-1 px-2">
                        <p class="mt-0">(l) item #2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-left mb-1 px-2">
                        <p class="mt-0">(l) item #3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-left mb-1 px-2">
                        <p class="mt-0">(l) item #4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-left mb-1 px-2">
                        <p class="mt-0">(l) item #5</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- content_left-->
        <div class="col-sm-6 h-100">
            <div id="content_right" class=" d-flex flex-column p-2">
                <div class="h5 w-100" style="background:#fff; text-align:center;">Right</div>
                <div class="wrapper-right">
                    <div class="row mx-1 mb-1">
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p class="mt-0">(r) item #1</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p class="mt-0">(r) item #2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mx-1 mb-1">
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #3</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #4</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mx-1 mb-1">
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #5</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #6</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mx-1 mb-1">
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #7</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #8</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mx-1 mb-1">
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #9</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #10</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mx-1 mb-1">
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #11</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #12</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mx-1 mb-1">
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #13</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 item-right px-2">
                            <p>(r) item #14</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- content_right -->
    </div> <!-- content -->
</div>
```

For future reference, it's better to include your code using the snippet tool, rather than using a link to a third-party site.

Comment: This helps make it more bootstrap-ic, but...one goal here was some white space between the beige items on the right, which are col-6 within a row. Played with many variations of margins, padding & widths for them, to no avail. If I give them a border I can fake space - may have to leave it at that. Thx

Comment: Bootstrap columns touch the adjacent columns. If you add margin, it will make the column too wide for the row and it will wrap to the next line. You can adjust the padding, but since you have the background color assigned to the column, you won’t see any difference. If you want the content inside your beige boxes separated, either you can add a division inside the column or you could use a border. I’ve added a white border to my example.